# UILabel AutoShrink property in not working in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uilabel

I added Autoshrink Property of my label from nib file as follow;

[image: AutoShrink]

**It is working good in ios6 but not effected in ios7.**

**ios6**:

[image]

**ios7**

[image]

**Why this happen?** I am using `numberoflines=2`

**Help to solve this**

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is because you are using

```
 numberOfLines = 2
```

that means your label will be of two lines, so its auto adjusting the size accordingly as your label will be of 2 lines, 
set background color of the Label to get to know about the label dimension.

EDIT - 
If you want your labeltext to fit someother Superview element accordingly and have thinking that your label can have a text too long, then set numberOfLines = 0.

Basically numberOfLines  means the Maximum line breaks the text of the label can have

Set your FONT to a lower value - 14,13 (judging by your previous one that is what i am sensing)
Set your Label to a fixed width, so that you know that a nextLine would appear after that width,
Set Number of lines to  0

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what is the solution of this?

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve, i will answer in an EDIT

Comment: I set numberLines=0 still not affecting in ios7

Comment: decrease the width of the label and Keep Autoshrink to "Fixed "